# Why my ajax post is not working codeigniter? The page is refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```js
 // save new employee record
            $('#saveEmpForm').submit('click',function(){
                var empInputId = $('#input_id').val();
                var empJenis = $('#jenis').val();
                var empJarak = $('#jarak').val();
               
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "InputPembangunan/save",
                    dataType : "JSON",
                    data : {input_id:empInputId, jenis:empJenis, jarak:empJarak },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#jenis').val("");
                        $('#jarak').val("");
                        $('#addEmpModal').modal('hide');
                        alert('Successfully called');
                        listEmployee();
                    },
                    error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                        alert('Exception:', exception);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

```html
<form id="saveEmpForm" method="post">
    <div class="modal fade" id="addEmpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Employee</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">                       
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Jenis</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="jenis" id="jenis" class="form-control" required>
            <input type="hidden" id="input_id"  name="input_id" class="form-control " value="{$input_id}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Jarak</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input type="text" name="jarak" id="jarak" class="form-control" required> 
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Save function in controller file

```
public function save(){
        $data=$this->inputs_model->saveEmp();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Save function in Model

```
public function saveEmp(){
        $data = array(              
                'input_id'          => $this->input->post('input_id'), 
                'jenis'             => $this->input->post('jenis'), 
                'jarak'             => $this->input->post('jarak'), 
                'created_at'        => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),
                'updated_at'        => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")
            );
        $result=$this->db->insert('input_jenis_industri',$data);
        return $result;
    }
```

The code are as stated above, my ajax function to save the data is not working. It is not saving the data in the db. What can cause the problem?

My ajax function calls the InputPembangunan/save to save the data, then the controller try to the save data using the save() function. It is saved using the model saveEmp()

Comment: after save(){echo `"testing";`} in controller & check it prints or not?

Comment: also you included <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>?

Comment: As Kumar asked - have you loaded a jquery library in your page so that the jquery will actually run. And how are you debugging this?

Comment: I have loaded jquery in the page, it version 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The following is incorrect, there is no click involved in a [submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$('#saveEmpForm').submit('click',function(){
```

Change to

```
$('#saveEmpForm').submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault()// prevent normal form submit
```

Comment: I tried the advice, but the page is still refreshing. Please help. Is my controller and model is correct?

Comment: Try wrapping this in `$(function(){ /* submit listener code */ })` to make sure the form exists when it runs. ALso check errors in browser dev tools console (F12)

Answer (score 0):

without refreshing the page you have to call event.preventDefault() method after submit event.

replace this

```
    $('#saveEmpForm').submit('click',function(){
```

with

```
    $('#saveEmpForm').on('submit',function(){
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: it is still refreshing. Is my controller and model accurate?

Comment: try once more with above changes

Answer (score 0):

**Change this**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

**to**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Comment: Now submit event won't trigger on `form#saveEmpForm` using type=button

Answer (score 0):

You can `onlick()` method. Actually I used like this;

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
```

than add jquery

```
function save() {
// ajax adding data to database
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    URL: "<?php echo site_url('InputPembangunan/save')?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            reload_table();
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //do error form
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following way,

```
$( "#saveEmpForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    /** Your Existing Code ***/
    var empInputId = $('#input_id').val();
    var empJenis = $('#jenis').val();
    var empJarak = $('#jarak').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "InputPembangunan/save",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data : {input_id:empInputId, jenis:empJenis, jarak:empJarak },
        success: function(data){
            $('#jenis').val("");
            $('#jarak').val("");
            $('#addEmpModal').modal('hide');
            alert('Successfully called');
            listEmployee();
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            alert('Exception:', exception);
        }
    });
    return false;
    /** Your Existing Code ***/
});
```

Also, you can check the jQuery reference from this link:
https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('#saveEmpForm').submit('click',function(){
```

with

```
$(document).off('submit','#saveEmpForm').on('submit','#saveEmpForm',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent default submit action
    ...rest of the code
})
```

also check for any errors on the browser dev tool